# Magento 2 + need to use fotorama in cms page

Tags: magento2, fotorama, fotorama-slider

Is there any way to use fotorama slider in CMS pages?

**Slider:**

```
<div id="fotorama_test" class="fotorama">
  <img src="https://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">
  <img src="https://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Note: To solve this problem, first look at the answer of @Prince and then at the answer of "Pritam Info 24"

Answer (score 3):

## **CSS:**

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/fotorama.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

## **JS:**

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            fotorama: 'js/fotorama'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/fotorama.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict"; // <-- this might cause some problems which you need to resolve, otherwise the code won't work. You can also just remove it.
       return function fotorama()
       {
           alert('load fotorama OK');
           //put the fotorama.js content here (you get it from your library)
       }
});
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/fotorama_slider.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'fotorama'], function($, fotorama) {
        fotorama();
    });
</script>
```

and finaly you load your fotorama slider (fotorama_slider.phtml) into your cms page like this :

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::fotorama_slider.phtml"}}
```

**Info:** don't forget to :

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` content
- clean `pub/static` content
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Not working, please can you able to post  fotoram_slider.phtml content as well.

Comment: `fotoram_slider.phtml` is already posted : `<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'fotorama'], function($, fotorama) {
        fotorama();
    });
</script>`

Comment: thanks for the reply but it's not working

Comment: Look if you have some js error

Comment: @PЯINCƏ, I also tried it, I get `Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'mytheme/base::fotorama_slider.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\framework\view\element\template_0'`

Comment: @PЯINCƏ, I had to use `{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::fotorama_slider.phtml"}}` Now the template loads. But there is no gallery showing.

Comment: Works fine for me. Just there was a js error  ( because the strict mode) for variable  fotoramaVersion in the js file app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/fotorama.js and fixed by  declaring   the variable "var fotoramaVersion" before the  fotorama.js content.

Comment: @PЯINCƏ, "**//put the fotorama.js content here (you get it from your library)**" Do you mean we should copy the content from `lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.min.js` to this line? Is this really how it is intendet?! This seems dirty to me. However... I tried it, but the gallery is still not working. There are no errors in the console too.

Comment: @PritamInfo24, can you show me your fotorama CMS content please?

Comment: @Black I tried it in M2.2 but it should works on other M2 versions as well. Make sure fotorama.js and fotorama.css are loaded properly without any JS error. Please see my updated ans.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. CMS page content is very straight forward as describe [here](https://fotorama.io/.)

**Note** : I put my fotorama CMS page content   in ans section for better readability. I am not giving the full ans of your queation as @PЯINCƏ already answered it.

1) My fotorama CMS page content :

```
    <center>
    <div class="fotorama"  data-allowfullscreen="native"  data-transition="crossfade" data-nav="thumbs"  data-width="700" data-ratio="700/467" data-max-width="100%">
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/1-lo.jpg"}}" /> 
    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/2-lo.jpg"}}" /> 
    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/5-lo.jpg"}}" /> 
    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/6-lo.jpg"}}" /> 
    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/9-lo.jpg"}}" />
    </div>
    </center>
    <p>{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::fotorama_slider.phtml"}}
    </p>
```

2) My 
***app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js***

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        '*' : {              
               'fotorama': 'js/fotorama'
             }
    }    
};
```

3) My
***app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/fotorama.js***

**Note :** I have downloaded **fotorama.js** from https://fotorama.io/ and put the fotorama.js lib code in that file (*app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/fotorama.js*)  just below the line **//put the fotorama.js content here (you get it from your library)**

```
/*!
 * Fotorama 4.6.4 | http://fotorama.io/license/
 */
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function fotorama()
       {
           //alert('load fotorama OK');

           var fotoramaVersion;
           //put the fotorama.js content here (you get it from your library)
           fotoramaVersion="4.6.4",function(a,b,c,d,e){"use strict";function f......
           ........................
       }
})
```

At Fronted it look ilks:

[image]

Comment: It finally works now after using your **app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/fotorama.js)** code! :) I even attempted it before myself...but I put the `var` directly at the `fotoramaVersion` and not like you did... bruh. If you remove `use strict;` then it works too. Thanks :)

Comment: Good to know that it works finally. Thank you.