# How to use fotorama in my custom widget?

Tags: magento2, javascript, widget, fotorama

I want to display my product image gallery in my custom widget.
`$images = $_item->getMediaGalleryImages();` is how I got my images for product.

I want to display the image using fotorama? is this possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out:

Found this link [Magento 2 + need to use fotorama in cms page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290496/magento-2-need-to-use-fotorama-in-cms-page/290497)

Load it to custom template phtml file

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()
         ->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')
         ->setTemplate('Magento_Theme::fotorama_slider.phtml')
         ->toHtml();
?>
```